# Jenkins Remote Trigger User Name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I am developing a Dashboard on top of Jenkins. The Dashboard would list all the jobs available and would also have a trigger button to initiate a build which shoots a post request using the secret token. The problem is every build would have the same cause which says "Started by remote host 19.XX.XX.XX". Since the dashboard needs to display the user name triggering the job as the person who logged, is there a way we can pass the a username as  well in the jenkins remote trigger url like below so that jenkins would capture the cause as the user name.

```
https://jenkinsurl:port/job/testLDAP/build?token=DDJjk$#@@*bB&userName=abc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no parameter that you can use for this. A workaround that I've used is adding `&cause=This+was+started+by+abc` which results in

> Started by remote host 192.168.x.x with note: This was started by abc

Perhaps this might help you.